# Having good domain name and using domain aliases (I use notlong)?

Tags: domains, url-shorteners

I use only free servers and after creating my website I decided to make access to that domain by **simple domain name** . I decided to use domain alias notlong service
  The second advantage of using alias here was to be **independant from my file host** which I will have to change. 
  I haven't found a better alias service like *notlong*, because *notlong* is **easy to remember**.
  After that I encounter many problems:
* most of forums or social services treat *notlong* address as a **spam**,
* Bing so far haven't accepted the notlong domain and others.

---

Is it another way **to have good free domain name**?
  How about the situation **when your hosting server will inform you to expire**? Only a lasting layer of domain aliases make you independent from the real file hosts.

Comment: I think you may have the same problem with any free domain providers. Because they are free they are likely being abused by spammers on a regular basis.

Comment: A domain is around, roughly, $10. For $10, you'll seem much more professional and most likely be accepted into bing far quicker, *right*?

Answer (score 2):

Just like Sherwin Flight said, if you find a free domain not considered as spam, it's probably a new domain.

From what I see, your site doesn't use server-side scripts, so you can use Google App Engine server to host static files, and you also won't have any advertisements there! It's a little more tricky then `republika.pl` server, though:
http://www.instantfundas.com/2011/02/how-to-host-static-websites-on-google.html.

And remember, in most cases people won't type whole address into URL field of a browser. Nowadays it's often enough to type only one letter to make Firefox suggest you your favorite site. And if You cleaned the history and don't remember the address, Google will help. That's why big companies often don't care that someone bought a domain with their product name, e.g. `torchlight2.com` and they create another, longer domain, e.g. `torchlight2game.com`.